# In Compose, LazyColumn does not display new items when the user keeps scrolling down

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In the provided example code, where LazyColumn adds a new item every second, when a new item has already scrolled out of view, if I continue scrolling down, it keeps triggering the bounce effect, and the new item doesn't appear immediately.

```kotlin
    @Composable
    fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
        val listState = rememberLazyListState()
        var list by remember { mutableStateOf(mutableStateListOf<String>("A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"))}
        LaunchedEffect(Unit){
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                var cnt=0
                while(true){
                    delay(1000)
                    list.add("${++cnt}")
                }
            }
        }
        LazyColumn(state = listState){
            itemsIndexed(list){i,v->
                key(i){
                    Text(v, fontSize = 30.sp)
                }
    
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the current test diagram.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDLI0.gif)

I hope to seamlessly scroll to new items during continuous scrolling gestures without having to wait for about 1 second to see the new items. Is there a way to achieve this seamless scrolling to new items effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is `Paging` like functionality but you are doing it after a certain delay that's why the list is not showing the new loaded items.

**Note:** One thing you can get in your mind is to scroll the list to the end if any new element is added using `listState.scrollToItem(list.lastIndex)` but that also won't work in the case when user doesn't want to scroll.

**So you have to load data prior to the user scrolls to the end and that's how when user reach the end then there will be more data to show which gives you the required seemless scrolling experience.**

> Given the last visible item in an app's UI, the number of items beyond this last item that the Paging Library should attempt to fetch in advance. This value should be several times larger than the page size.

This is mentioned in the official docs of the google for Paging library, you can check it at: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/data#define-paging-config

[image: Paging preview]

By this approach you can get the expected behaviour as shown in preview and you should also show some loader in the end of the list as implemented in the preview to handle the delay like the data takes more time to load and user reach the end before loading the next data. By this the user will also have great experience.